# Disable server side caching in rails production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am about to deploy an application with sensitive data. For that reason, there should not be any data stored to disk. Is there a way to disable server side caching? I could not find any.

Comment: Are you talking about log files and console output?

Comment: Hi, I mean the files that are created under tmp/cache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I happened to come across this question and am assuming you no longer need an answer. However, I believe what you're looking for is the following:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

Comment: I haven't tested this myself, since the question is quite old, but I assume that it is the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

set these settings in your configuration file.  *i-e* `config/environments/production.rb`

`config.perform_caching = false
config.cache_store = :null_store`

Answer (score -2):

Your requirement doesn't make sense as stated. If you have "sensitive data", where is that data being stored? In a database, probably? If so, then server-side caching will not be any greater security risk.

Lots of applications involve sensitive data. So make the server secure; don't turn off caching.

If I misunderstood your setup, please explain further.

Comment: Well the database resides on a different server and I am not storing the database passwords in database.yml, but rather have the user enter them upon login (that wasn't easy to do, but works now). The rails server can be accessed by administrators and they should not be able to look into the sensitive data. I don't see why the rails application should absolutely have to store data on disk, since I have no performance issues that would need caching. I just want to turn that off. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes: the whole setup doesn't make sense. Are all the users entering passwords to the same DB, or to different DBs? And particularly if the DB is on a different server, you're probably going to want caching, or else you'll have lots of time lost to network traffic. And why shouldn't the admins see the data? Presumably they're more trusted than random users...

Comment: Look, I have one user (who isn't random at all), no performance issues and sensitive data. I can very well decide whether the setup makes sense. The question is: can I turn off disk caching in rails? Yes / No / I don't know. Please don't decide about the sense without knowing the whole background.

Comment: This is a common government requirement when dealing with data above UNCLASSIFIED. You CANNOT store any data on the server unless absolutely necessary / critical. This typically includes any caching mechanisms unless otherwise approved (good luck).

This is not an answer.

Comment: @Kris How about memcached, then?

Comment: @Marnen it all depends on the project and what you can and cannot get approved. Memcache may be allowed as long as it's hosted off the application server and handled in a similar fashion to a database but it's really up to the discretion on whoever is in charge of the project's security and IA. Even the usage of a session may be incredibly limited. I am not privy to the approval process itself and any guidelines beyond some I have learned during the process (such as any portion of data on the application server, even caching, can get your app tossed out).

Comment: @Kris "Memcache may be allowed as long as it's hosted off the application server" -- huh? That sounds like it would make security worse, not better. My idea with suggesting memcached was that it would be caching on the application server -- but not disk-based, so it wouldn't really expose another point of weakness. (Of course, to make sure of that, you'd have to not use virtual memory.) But then, I'm no security expert.

Comment: It all depends on contract requirements, how things are configured and if memcache is even approved for the secure environment. Unfortunately there are far too many details and requirements, many of which depend on very specific clearance levels of documents, that generalization of what you can and cannot do becomes very difficult. So in other words: fun :)

Comment: @Kris Contract requirements are sometimes poorly specified. I'm talking more about what makes sense from a technical point of view, consistent with security issues.