# File changes are not reflected in Docker webapp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I have a Rails app, trying to run it in Docker. I have a bind mount with the source code, but the web server does not reflect the changes. E.g. editing /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb makes no difference.

I then removed the bind mount, and edited directly in the container. Same thing happens. I have deleted the browser cache, but the old page is loaded every time. The inodes are the same before and after editing. Strangely - a drastic change like renaming the whole layouts directory makes a difference.

I would expect to see the files change as soon as I reload the page. This works as expected when run from the host, but not from docker.

Comment: Did you check if the server caches the content of the files server side? It sounds like the server in the docker container runs in a production environment, and has some kind of caching mechanism enabled. The server on your host likely runs in a development environment and does not have caching enabled. See here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136165/disable-server-side-caching-in-rails-production-environment/10485141

Comment: @jan-di your direction was right! Turns out its Rails itself that caches the app in memory - but for prod environment only. Both docker (configured as prod) and host (as dev) is on my local machine, so no other server inbetween. But I did some digging in config/environments/production.rb and set "config.cache_classes = false". The next option is eager loading, but it works as it is (true) so far. After some code tweaking, I will turn the cache on again before release. Feel free to post this cache-issue as the answer and refer or copy from here if needed. development.rb has some good info btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment, the issue is on the (application) server side.

`Turns out its Rails itself that caches the app in memory - but for prod environment only. Both docker (configured as prod) and host (as dev) is on my local machine, so no other server inbetween. But I did some digging in config/environments/production.rb and set "config.cache_classes = false".`